# How to get @FetchRequest respect fetchLimit when new records are added

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

When I query Core Data with @FetchRequest and fetchLimit - it works fine. But when new records are added to Core Data on the fly, the @FetchRequest adds them to the View but doesn't respect the fetchLimit anymore.

To replicate this, I've created a new default Project in Xcode and checked "Use Core Data", then created 5 new timestamps:

[Initial View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgrXU.png)

Then I added fetchLimit=3, and got only 3 results:

[Showing only 3 Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2otw.png)

But, when I click the plus button to add a new record - @FetchRequest updates the View on the fly, but four items are shown, instead of three:

[The fourth item gets added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R5O4.png)

Just in case I use this (pretty standard) code to add the fetchLimit:

```
//Instead of this:
/*@FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: false)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>*/

//I'm using this:
    @FetchRequest private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    init() {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: false)]

        //fetchLimit is set here:
        request.fetchLimit = 3
        _items = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: request)
    }
```

How can I make @FetchRequest keep updating the View reactively, but respect the fetchLimit to always show the latest 3 Items only?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I've stumbled upon the same issue today and I have NO idea how to make this work 